# Inverse Lapace transform of $F(s)=\frac{I_0(r\sqrt{n^2+s})}{s I_0(\sqrt{n^2+s})}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

While trying to solve [this diffusion-reaction problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638930/looking-for-analytical-solution-methods-to-pde-in-radial-coordinates-reaction-d/4491414#4491414), I encountered the following Laplace inversion problem:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}_s\left\{\frac{I_0(r\sqrt{n^2+s})}{s I_0(\sqrt{n^2+s})} \right\}\,,
\end{align}
with $0<r<1$, with $n$ a constant, $I_0$ a modified Bessel function of the first kind, and $s$ being the Laplace variable conjugate to time $t$. Can anyone help me solve this?

FYI: numerical Laplace inversions for $n=2$ and $t=10^{-4},10^{-2}$ and $1$ are shown below:
[image]

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpmath import *

def F(s,r,n):
    return mp.besseli(0,mp.sqrt(n**2+s)*r)/(s*mp.besseli(0,mp.sqrt(n**2+s)))

mp.dps = 20
def f(t,r,n):
    ft = lambda s: F(s,r,n)
    return invertlaplace(ft,t,method='talbot')

r  = np.linspace(0,1,200)
n  = 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(r,[f(1e-4,i,n) for i in r],'r',lw=1,label='$t=10^{-4}$')
ax.plot(r,[f(1e-2,i,n) for i in r],'g',lw=1,label='$t=10^{-2}$')
ax.plot(r,[f(1,i,n) for i in r],'b',lw=1,label='$t=1$')
ax.set(xlabel=r'$r$', ylabel=r'$f(r,t)$') 
ax.legend()
```

Comment: This looks like one of those nightmare integrals you turn to Gradshteyn and Rhyzhik for.

Comment: I can't find it in the 7th edition thereof.